# BizTalk: Outbound logical ports are not getting removed from orchestration

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2, biztalk-orchestrations

I have an orchestration that has 3 wcf-custom( with sqlbinding, calling stored procedures) adapters configured to 3 send ports. My requirement was to replace the WCF-Custom adapter calls with C# method method call.

I wrote the C# methods to call the stored procs and removed the 3 send ports from orchestration. I am using a cmd line tool (BTTask ExportApplication) to create an msi and imported it in admin console.

However, I can still see all 3 logical ports in orchestration bindings tab. I have tried cleaning the solution and building several times but it just wouldn't go. Am I missing something here?

I am using BizTalk 2013R2.

Comment: Have you re-started the host instances?

Comment: P.S. Why are you replacing WCF calls with C#?    Have you made sure your C# calls are thread safe?  Have you implemented retries and error handling?

Comment: Yes..I have restarted HIs...Retries and error handling is in place too..

Comment: Did you also run the MSI to re-gac the DLLs?

Comment: Yes..i did that too..but no luck...

Comment: Does the MSI actually include the updated code? Maybe an old build is used, or a new one isn't compiled at all?

Comment: As Ruud has said, make sure that the updated DLLs are actually being deployed, you can verify this by updating the Assembly File Version number (don't update the Assembly Version), and verify after your deployment that the DLL's in the GAC have the updated Assembly File Version number.  In fact we tend to do this as standard practice for all deployments outside of Dev.